# Error creating database in sequelize Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The error statement:
Error: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0 at new Sequelize (D:\tutorial\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:181:13) at Object. (D:\tutorial\util\database.js:3:19) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) at Object. (D:\tutorial\app.js:9:19) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3) at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12) at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19) at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

My database request is:

```
 const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('node_complete', 'root', 'Kornienko130', 'nodecomplete', {
dialect: 'mysql',
host: 'localhost',
});

module.exports = sequelize;
```

The dialect is explicitly stated, I don't know what's wrong, I googled it so many times and none of the solutions seems to work.

Comment: Have you try to initiate config json file? http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#installing-cli

Comment: I did try it with node_modules/.bin/sequelize init comand and nothing really changed.

Comment: It will create a config json file. You need to put passwords and stuff there too. By doing this it works for me. You code seems okay though I also little bit new to this